# swagger url problem with springdoc-openapi

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

This is not the story of springfox
This is the story of springdoc -openapi.

my current dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

my properties

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.packagesToScan=com.example
springdoc.pathsToMatch=/api/**
springdoc.cache.disabled= true
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

request here(localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html) my server responds swagger petstore example
I already know petstore disable (springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true),
but it's not working

Another problem is if I request here
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/v3/api-docs

[cannot read controller infomation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puSwd.png)
cannot read controller infomation

that you should always write /v3/api-docs in the input box

[/v3/api-docs in the input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7eFr.png)

I would like the contents of /v3/api-docs to come out like the second picture if you request swagger.html

How can I solve this problem?

thanks for reading have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading `springdoc-openapi-ui` dependency to version `1.6.8`

Comment: Thank you, a lot. Despite the fact that I have no idea why it works.